# É correto na, língua portuguesa, utilizar "a gente" como sinónimo de "nós"?

Tags: diferenças-transatlânticas, pronomes, concordância-verbal, locuções-pronominais

Tenho lido muito no SOpt a escreverem *a gente vamos* ou *a gente fomos* em vez de *nós vamos* e *nós fomos*.

Ao que parece no Brasil usa-se *a gente vai* e *a gente foi* como se *gente* fosse *povo* ou *pessoas*.

É correto, na língua portuguesa, utilizar *a gente*?

Comment: Correto eu diria que é, pois já usamos isso faz um bom tempo. Talvez uma forma mais interessante de se perguntar isso seria como que isso veio a acontecer.

Comment: O correto em ptBR é *a gente vai*, não "a gente vamos".

Comment: @bfavaretto *a gente vai*? Isso não me **parece** minimamente correto. Para começar, **acho** que  *a gente* assim empregado está errado, mas assumindo que é correto *a gente* é sinonimo de *nós* certo? Então *Nós vai* é errado.

Comment: pra mim a "gente" significa o "povo", as "pessoas", não acho correto utilizar para "nós"

Comment: @LucasMotta não tinha visto por essa perspetiva. Vou editar. Mas a pergunta mantém-se.

Comment: @LucasMotta se eu e você formos para a balada e você disser *a gente vai embora* a quem você se refere?

Comment: @JorgeB. acho que pode ser utilizado, mas em linguagem falada, não fica legal para linguagem escrita... Não quero ser hipócrita, eu utilizo muito "a gente fez", "A gente foi", etc...

Comment: @LucasMotta podes dar um ou dois exemplos de frases com esses termos?

Comment: "A gente fez as tarefas", "A gente jogou futebol", porem acho a escrita um tanto quanto estranho

Comment: @LucasMotta ou seja, *nós fizemos as tarefas* e *nós jogamos futebol* seriam frases sinonimas das suas?

Comment: Acho que eu precisaria pesquisar bastante para poder redigir uma resposta que te convença. Mas como falante nativo posso dizer que *a gente* (= *nós*), concordando com a terceira pessoa do singular, é extremamente comum no sudeste do Brasil (mais comum na língua falada do que na escrita, embora ocorra em ambas). Ocorre também a concordância com a primeira pessoa do plural (*a gente vamos*), mas essa forma é extremamente mal-vista, considerada sinal de baixa escolaridade.

Comment: Sim. Pra não confundir, acredito que possa ser utilizada ambas, porem acho melhor utilizar a gente apenas na linguagem falada.

Comment: @bfavaretto *a gente* deveria-se referir a ela ou elas, *a gente de Portugal é muito simpática* e não *a gente fez as tarefas*.

Comment: @JorgeB. Não adianta querer contestar os fatos da língua, eles não seguem essa lógica cartesiana.

Comment: Acho que em Portugal a expressão "a gente" (e "a malta", e "o povo") é usada como no brasil. **[O dicionário](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/gente)** concorda: `Locução que corresponde semanticamente ao pronome pessoal nós, mas gramaticalmente a uma terceira pessoa do singular (ex.: a gente vai chegar atrasada), e designa o grupo em que se integra quem fala ou escreve. = A MALTA` (Pus um comentário na excelente resposta do AndréSouzaLemos, para ele acrescentar esta fonte.)

Comment: @ANeves pelo menos aqui no norte não se usa *a gente*, pode ser que seja regionalismo. Perguntei porque me soa mal e já há muito tinha essa dúvida.

Comment: Existem muitas diferenças entre o ptPT e o ptBR.  Sempre que vou a Portugal descubro mais uma série de diferenças entre os dois povos - diferenças gramaticais, semânticas, linguísticas, culinárias, etc...   Muitas delas soam muito estranho àqueles que não as usam ou que nunca as ouviram.  Mas temos que aceitar como correto aquilo que tem o uso consagrado pelo povo, independente de que lado do Atlântico seja.  Até mesmo no Brasil, existem essas diferenças.  Nâo sou um adepto ferrenho da gramática normativa, mas também não considero correto aceitar qualquer tipo de "erro" na língua falada.

Comment: Encontrei dois artigos, da mesma autora, tratando desse tema. São ambos técnicos, e o mais recente é razoavelmente longo. Ela faz uma análise do uso de *a gente* no Brasil ao longo do tempo, levando em conta tanto fatores sociolinguísticos quanto a perda de traços formais e semânticos que foram levando à pronominalização dessa expressão. Cf [Lopes, 1998](http://www.scielo.br/scielo.php?pid=S0102-44501998000200006&script=sci_arttext) e [Lopes, 2004](https://periodicos.ufsc.br/index.php/forum/article/viewFile/7728/7098).

Comment: @bfavaretto obrigado :) E excelente pesquisa. Já me convenceu o uso de *a gente*

Comment: @Centaurus neste caso acho não ser uma diferença entre pt_PT e pt_BR visto que é usado nos dois países. Embora em algumas regiões não se use, a verdade é que é correto usar.

Comment: Esta frase está correta? Empreguei-a no sentido de: a respeito de, sobre.

Comment: A gente escreve "nós" mas dizemos "a gente".

Comment: Porém a construção "a gente falamos" é uma hipercorreção, a ser evitada em qualquer contexto exceto talvez para caracterizar de personagens em textos de ficção.

Comment: Acabam de me dizer de não colocar respostas nos comentários para a pergunta sobre Pois é. Aqui vejo que há muitas.......O que quer dizer correto?? Correto linguisticamente é uma coisa. Correto socialmente é outra.

Comment: @Lambie não entendi...

Comment: Está correto, mas é preciso conjugar corretamente. Por exemplo, "nós não somos parvos" será "a gente não é parva".

Comment: Esse trem nunca acaba?? :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

"A gente" é uma [locução pronominal](http://www.recantodasletras.com.br/gramatica/2588306), que apesar de se usar no lugar do pronome pessoal "nós", corresponde gramaticalmente à terceira pessoa do singular, e portanto faz com que o verbo seja conjugado de acordo:

> Nós vamos / A gente [ela] vai
>
> Nós não queremos só comida / A gente [ela] não quer só comida

O uso dessa forma tem origem metonímica. Troca-se "nós" por "a gente", assim como por exemplo se troca "nós brasileiros" por "o Brasil". É um movimento na direção da impessoalidade, de um afeto coletivo, aberto:

> Nós [brasileiros] queremos / O Brasil [o povo, *a gente*] quer

É uma forma de uso coloquial e portanto é estranho utilizá-la em situações que fogem desse registro da língua:

> Nós iremos / A gente irá

**Adendo:**

O aparecimento da forma "a gente" pode ser o reparo da dificuldade do uso do "nós" como [pronome exclusivo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusividade_(lingu%C3%ADstica)) (aquele que exclui o ouvinte, ou um referido suposto, do coletivo em questão).

Comment: @AndréSouzaLemos pode citar como fonte gramatical **[o dicionário priberam](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/gente)**: `Locução que corresponde semanticamente ao pronome pessoal nós, mas gramaticalmente a uma terceira pessoa do singular (ex.: a gente vai chegar atrasada), e designa o grupo em que se integra quem fala ou escreve. = A MALTA`

Answer (score 9):

Em ptBR **"a gente" significando "nós" tem uso consagrado e é correto.** No entanto a concordância se faz com a terceira pessoa do singular.

- "Ei, moço, a gente está procurando a Praça D. Pedro IV.  Pode nos informar onde fica? (sei que não se chama um homem de moço em ptPT mas é muito comum em ptBR)
- "A gente tentou te encontrar mas foi inútil" (nós tentamos)

Contudo, "a gente" também tem outros significados:

- A minha gente está passando fome.  Não há alimento. (pode ser meu povo, meus familiares, depende do contexto)
- Aquela gente não presta. (aquelas pessoas)

Answer (score 6):

Descobri, ao fim de dois meses, esta discussão extraordinária, e fiquei banzado! É claro *a gente vai, a gente faz, etc.* no sentido de *nós vamos, nós fazemos* é correto, pertencendo simplesmente a um registo informal. E é claro que a gente aqui em Portugal também fala assim.  Creio que menos que no passado, mas ainda se ouve muito. O objetivo desta resposta é sobretudo dar conta do uso em Portugal, mas como o reconhecimento de um uso no dicionário tem o seu peso, aqui fica o que diz o Dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa (2001):

> **a gente**, *locução pronominal, Familiar*, funciona como uma terceira pessoa gramatical do singular e indica o grupo de pessoas em que se integra quem fala ou escreve, sendo equivalente a «nós» semanticamente, mas não gramaticalmente. *A gente nem sabe o que fazer. A gente vai hoje ao cinema*.

O dicionário Houaiss (Lisboa, 2003) corrobora:

> **a gente** [...] **2** a pessoa que fala em nome de si própria e de outro(s); nós <*a gente resolveu mudar-se para o campo*> […] GRAMÁTICA/USO a locução pronominal *a gente* deve usar-se com o verbo na 3.ª pessoa do singular; a sua equivalência semântica ao pronome *nós* leva por vezes ao uso indevido do verbo na 1.ª pessoa do plural

O [Cibrdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/sobre-a-silepse-na-concordancia-com-a-gente/29794) também reprova estes *a gente vamos, a gente fazemos*, etc. Mas a *Gramática do Português* da Gulbenkian (Lisboa 2013), menos sentenciosa, diz apenas (p. 900):

> [...] num registo coloquial menos cuidado, *a gente* determina frequentemente concordância na 1.ª pessoa do plural (cf. *a gente, logo, **vamos** ao cinema*), embora esta variante seja estigmatizada na norma-padrão.

Na minha experiência, no entanto, quando se começa com *a gente*, o primeiro ou primeiros verbos vão para a terceira pessoa do singular, mas mais à frente, passa-se normalmente para a primeira do plural, como fala [Roberta Medina em “No Brasil já perdoaram termos trazido o Rock in Rio para Portugal”, *Sol*, 2016](http://sol.sapo.pt/artigo/511658/roberta-medina-no-brasil-ja-perdoaram-termos-trazido-o-rock-ir-rio-para-portugal-) (ênfase minha em todas as citações):

> Quando **a gente chegou** a Portugal em 2003, para preparar a edição de 2004, **percebemos** muito rápido que os 19 anos de história que o RiR tinha no Brasil era algo legal, mas as pessoas queriam era que se construísse uma história nova do RiR, aqui em Portugal.

Quanto ao uso em Portugal, [este corpus de falares rurais](http://www.clul.ul.pt/pt/recursos/226-corpus-syntax-oriented-corpus-of-portuguese-dialects-cordial-sin) reúne entrevistas efetuadas em 31 localidades espalhadas por todo o Portugal continental, e registou o uso de *a gente* em todas elas. Em 18 das 31 *a gente* é mais frequente que *nós* juntamente com conjugação na primeira pessoa do plural sem sujeito. (Resultados por localidade estão sintetizados [nesta tese de mestrado](http://www.clul.ul.pt/files/ana_maria_martins/Ns_a_gente_e_o_sujeito_nulo_de_1PL.pdf), p. 75 e seguintes.) As entrevistas foram feitas entre 1974 e 2004, e os entrevistados eram todos idosos com pouca instrução escolar ([a metadata está aqui](http://www.meertens.knaw.nl/edisyn/searchengine/?action=metadata_cordialsin)). Portanto na altura, estes entrevistados já não eram representativos do país todo; seriam mais representativos do que Portugal tinha sido uns cinquenta anos antes, quando eles eram jovens adultos e Portugal era um país essencialmente rural.

Isto corresponde à minha experiência pessoal. Quando eu era criança, nos anos setenta, numa zona rural a uns 50 km a norte de Lisboa, *a gente* era como os meus avós, os meus pais, e a maior parte das pessoas da geração deles, falava. Mas *a gente* era visto por pessoas mais instruídas como uma forma menos culta, o que corresponde à ideia expressa por alguns comentadores brasileiros aqui nesta pergunta que *a gente* é mais aceitável na fala que na escrita. Eu lembro-me de, quando empregava *a gente* junto de algumas pessoas mais instruídas, ser corrigido com um “agente é da polícia.” Também se ouvia *a gente vamos, a gente fazemos*, etc.

Agora, apesar de ser menos frequente atualmente, ainda se encontra *a gente*, na literatura, claro, mas mesmo na comunicação social:

> [[Maria Irene, Porto, à estação de rádio TSF em 21-10-2015]](http://www.tsf.pt/sociedade/interior/rui-moreira-quer-aproveitar-ilhas-do-porto-para-habitacao-social-4847442.html) "O meu filho morou aqui, saiu queria que eu fosse com eles, mas estou habituada aqui, gosto muito disto aqui. A vizinhança é boa, **a gente tem** muita limpeza e se não tem começa logo a mandar vir umas com as outras"
>
> [[Fernando Santos, treinador da seleção portuguesa de futebol, à RTP em 14-11-2014]](http://www.rtp.pt/noticias/futebol-internacional/nem-que-seja-com-um-pau-a-gente-vai-ter-de-ganhar-afirma-fernando-santos_v782038) "Nem que seja com um pau, **a gente vai ter** de ganhar." [E ganharam, 1-0, frente à Arménia, em casa; se era preciso um pau!]
>
> “Vou a tremer toda.” — “Não estejas assim, cachopa, que eles não comem gente.” — “Mas levamos alguma trancada.” — “E **a gente dá-lhes** outra.”([Alves Redol](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alves_Redol), *Fanga*, 1943)

Frequentemente a locução pronominal *a gente*, como observa o Artefacto num comentário abaixo, refere um grupo indefinido, tipicamente muito alargado, em que o locutor se inclui; é como se dissesse *uma pessoa* ou *uma pessoa típica*:

> [[Ancião de 100 anos ao Correio da Manhã em 11-9-2016]](http://www.cmjornal.pt/mais-cm/domingo/imprimir/belas-historias-tem-100-anos) **A gente chega** a uma idade em que tende a entregar-se à preguiça
>
> [Luís Figo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lu%C3%ADs_Figo), ao jornal Expresso em 11-1-97] "E **a gente também vai** aprendendo com as coisas más: aprendi muito, quer quanto às relações humanas, quer quanto às profissionais."

Portanto a única diferença transatlântica aqui é que a locução pronominal *a gente* tem vindo a ser empregue cada vez mais no Brasil (vejam a tese de mestrado citada acima) enquanto que a gente aqui em Portugal a usa menos que no passado.

Comment: Tens dados que  mostrem que o uso de "a gente" está de facto a descrescer em Portugal? Tenho dúvidas de que seja de facto o caso. Em todo o caso, diria que a diferença entre a "a gente" e "nós" não é apenas de registo e que "a gente" tende a ser mais usada em situações mais abstratas em que não se quer focar tanto o sujeito.

Comment: @Artefacto Eu baseei-me na minha experiência pessoal. Mas arranjei uns dados informais. Considero o CORDIAL-SIN representivo do Portugal da 1ª metade do sec. XX. Considerando só *a gente* e *nós explícito*, na média das 31 localidades, *a gente* faz 79% das ocorrências. Fazendo uma busca restrita a Portugal no google, "a gente vai" -"toda a gente" dá 22 páginas; "nós vamos" dá 36. Até "o pessoal vai" dá 26, mais que *a gente vai*.

Comment: @Artefacto De qualquer maneira, "cair em desuso" é demasiado forte. Das coisas que fui vendo também fiquei com a ideia que, em muitas das vezes que o pessoal diz "a gente vai", a *a gente* podia abarcar um grupo alargado e indefinido de pessoas em que o locutor se inclui, como no exemplo do Luís Figo, e até um pouco nos dois primeiros. Mas na minha infância, havia muita gente que usava *a gente* para tudo, como no exemplo do Alves Redol.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31185/discussion-between-jacinto-and-jorge-b).

Comment: @Jacinto   Encontro-me em Portugal e tenho ouvido o povo usar "a gente", no Porto, em Braga, e nos Açores,  com a concordância sempre  à primeira pessoa do plural.  Não ouvi "a gente vai" uma única vez, mas ouvi "a gente vamos", "a gente fomos", etc.  Pode ser que minha amostragem seja viciada (meia idade e menos instrução), não sei.

Comment: @Centaurus Interessante Eu, na zona de Lisboa, não ouço muito *a gente*, ou então não presto atenção. Mas procurei no Google, restringindo a Portugal: encontrei 213 ocorrências de *a gente vai* e muito poucas de *a gente vamos*; o Google dá 118, mas a maior parte são falsos positivos (*vem partilhar com a gente. Vamos conseguir*); *a gente está* - 158; *a gente estamos* 48, a maior parte novamente falsos positivos.

Comment: @Jacinto Mas o Google pesquisa a língua escrita.  Creio que se fossem pesquisar a língua falada pelas pessoas nas ruas, incluindo aquelas com pouca instrução, o resultado seria diferente.

Comment: @Centaurus Eu vi o Google geral, não o Books. Aquilo tem tudo. Agora, estive a ver alguns resultados, e apesar de ter escolhido a opção "Portugal" na busca, parece-me uma grande parte dos resultados são de brasileiros. Mas tens aqui o [CORDIAL-SIN](http://www.clul.ul.pt/pt/recursos/413-cordial-corpus-normalized-transcription), um coleção de depoimentos de pessoas idosas de baixa instrução. Eu vi algumas delas e só encontrei concordância na terceira pessoa do singular. Forma recolhidas em zonas rurais entre 1974 e 2004, não sei se isso fará diferença.

Comment: @Jacinto  Minha observação deve então ter sido uma coincidência.  Ouvi umas 4 ou 5 pessoas e não me pareciam cultas (comerciantes, motorista de taxi, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Brava gente brasileira! (Hino da Independência do Brasil). É impressionante a quantidade de gente que procura corromper a língua! Sou um cidadão comum e desprovido de qualquer especialidade na Língua Portuguesa, mas sempre observei que os que usam "gente" no sentido de nós, não sabem o que estão fazendo, fazendo-o simplesmente por ignorância. Então, acham interessante transformar a ignorância em "costume", pensamento acompanhado por muitos "letrados", que incapazes de corrigir e ensinar, preferem ser simpáticos e adotar o errado como "uso" aceitável. Isso traz muita confusão e dificulta o entendimento. Nós precisamos combater esse tipo de pensamento, senão a gente que amamos permanecerá ignorante e acessível à corrupção.

Comment: User12112, bem-vindo ao site. Nós aqui pretendemos respostas fundamentadas.  Os dicionários e gramáticas que consultei não dizem que "a gente" no sentido 'nós' está errado. Tu dizes que está... baseias-te em quê? Tu dizes que o "costume" não faz o português correto. Olha que isso pode ser uma noção problemática. O que é o português correto? Será o dos grandes autores do século XIX? Será o do Camões? Vamos passar a dizer “ũa”, como ele? “Uma” é corrupção. E mesmo o Camões é corrupção do português medieval...

Comment: Como o comentário do Jacinto já deixa claro, só as línguas mortas não mudam e o português não é exceção (na verdade até o latim ganha palavras novas para descrever inovações tecnológicas). Línguas vivas estão sempre em fluxo — existem razões fisiológicas, psicológicas, tecnológicas, históricas, entre outras para essas mudanças ([por exemplo](https://novaescola.org.br/conteudo/2604/a-lingua-e-viva)), e apenas uma cultura relativamente homogênea, que amplamente suporte o purismo linguístico e tenha instituições (de ensino, etc.) fortes para sustentá-lo podem frear essas mudanças. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) Na Islândia há [algo assim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_purism_in_Icelandic), e vale notar que nem lá eles conseguem evitar mudanças como empréstimos linguísticos. Veja, a padronização da língua é importante, pois de fato facilita a comunicação; mas o esforço que é preciso dispender para *permanentemente* evitar todo desvio desse padrão é desproporcional à qualquer possível vantagem — e, se pode argumentar, completamente inviável para uma população tão grande e diversa quanto à lusófona.

Comment: User12112, talvez estejas interessado [nesta discussão sobre o que é a norma culta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/7790/onde-se-localiza-o-site-documento-oficial-da-norma-culta). Tal como tu, ninguém aqui é especialista em língua portuguesa -- somos meros interessados -- portanto vale a pena ver o que diz quem é especialista: o link acima são excertos da palestra dum linguista (com link à palestra completa, para quem estiver interessado), e é muito relevante para esta discussão aqui sobre o que é correto e o que não é.