# Quando é que se começou a usar a locução pronominal "a gente"?

Tags: origem-histórica, locuções-pronominais

A locução pronominal ***a gente*** emprega-se com o valor de ‘nós’, para referir o grupo concreto de pessoas em que o locutor se inclui:

> —A gente vai ao cinema hoje. Queres vir com a gente?

E emprega-se também para referir um grupo indefinido, pessoas em geral, em que o locutor se inclui:

> —A gente faz tudo pelos filhos; depois eles vão-se embora e não querem mais  saber da gente.

Nós já temos [esta pergunta sobre a correção e uso de *a gente*](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1026/%C3%89-correto-na-l%C3%ADngua-portuguesa-utilizar-a-gente-como-sin%C3%B3nimo-de-n%C3%B3s). O que eu quero saber aqui é quando e como é que a locução começou a ser usada em cada uma das suas aceções.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Decidi colocar uns trechos de este estudo: 
**De gente para a gente: o século XIX como fase de transição**
 por
Célia Regina dos Santos Lopes/Universidade Federal do Rio de Janeiro
Aqui [1](http://www.letras.ufrj.br/posverna/docentes/70994-3.pdf)

Segundo este ótimo estudo, não é nada novo: 
[...]
"2. Da cronologia de (a) gente em tempo real de longa duração
Com a quantificação da cronologia de (a) gente em tempo real de longa
duração, percebeu-se, na análise dos resultados, que o processo de pronominalização do substantivo gente foi lento e gradual, uma vez que só foram localizadas ocorrências de a gente como pronome no século **XVIII. Antes disso, há exemplos esporádicos em que a forma a gente apresenta ambigüidade interpretativa, ou seja, tanto pode ser considerada sinônimo de “pessoas” quanto variante de nós**.

Século XIII:
“O jograr por tod' aquesto | non deu ren, mas violou
como x´ ante violava, | e a candea pousou
outra vez ena vyola;| mas o monge lla cuidou
fillar, mas disse-ll' **a gente**: | "Esto vos non sofreremos."
A virgem Santa Maria... (p. 27 V. I, CSM, Século XIII)"

[...]"Tais ocorrências, escassas no português arcaico, começam a se tornar freqüentes a partir do século XVI. Localizou-se apenas um (01) exemplo no XIII, entretanto, **a partir do século XVI a incidência de exemplos dessa natureza torna-se mais
significativa**. Identificaram-se 2 casos de interpretação ambígua no XVI, 2 no XVII, 9 no XVIII e 36 no XIX."

[...] Figura4.5:Percurso histórico de gente (substantivo) > a gente (pronome)
///
A coisa começa ficar quente a partir du século XVIII!

"Como foi observado, é no século XIX que a gramaticalização de a gente começa
a se delinear com maior clareza. Ao contrário do período anterior (séculos XVII-XVIII) o número de dados da forma pronominal é mais significativo"

Comment: Excelente achado!

Comment: @Jacinto Foi mesmo. Feliz Ano Novo!