# Porque razão utilizamos a gente em substituição de nós?

Tags: etimologia, português-europeu, definição

Porque razão utilizamos "a gente" em substituição de nós?
Na escola a professora dizia que o Agente era da policia

Agente ser da policia, mas é usado separado A gente que afinal é sinónimo de nós

Comment: A gente (palavra separada) e é diferente de Agente... Mas não vejo em Portugal ser usado, vejo os Portugueses dizer: Toda a gente. E do "Toda a gente", acredito que o Brasileiro foi cortando até ficar apenas "A gente".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Quando é que se começou a usar a locução pronominal "a gente"?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/4009/quando-%c3%a9-que-se-come%c3%a7ou-a-usar-a-locu%c3%a7%c3%a3o-pronominal-a-gente)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> As duas expressões, a gente e nós, estão corretas, existem na língua
>   portuguesa e são utilizadas com frequência pelos falantes. A palavra
>   nós, como você já deve saber, é um pronome pessoal reto que indica
>   ideia de grupo. A palavra gente é um substantivo que também pode
>   desempenhar a função de locução pronominal e, ao exercer essa função
>   na frase, adquire o mesmo valor semântico do nós. O que isso quer
>   dizer? Quer dizer que as expressões a gente e nós são sinônimas.

E mais um pouco de explicação:

> Você deve ter percebido que o sentido não foi alterado quando
>   substituímos o pronome pessoal reto pela locução pronominal, não é
>   mesmo? O que mudou foi a conjugação verbal. O pronome nós deverá ser
>   utilizado com o verbo conjugado na primeira pessoa do plural, enquanto
>   a locução a gente deverá vir acompanhada do verbo conjugado na
>   terceira pessoa do singular, pois equivale ao pronome pessoal ela

Fonte: [Escola Kids - UOL](https://escolakids.uol.com.br/portugues/a-gente-ou-nos.htm)

Por outro lado, *a gente* está associado a linguagem coloquial e deve ser evitado em ambientes que necessita-se formalidade

> Trata-se de uma locução pronominal semanticamente equivalente ao
>   pronome nós. Deve ser conjugada na terceira pessoa do singular e
>   evitada na modalidade escrita (especialmente nos textos não
>   literários), já que está muito associada ao coloquialismo.

[Português - O seu sítio da Língua Portuguesa](https://www.portugues.com.br/gramatica/a-gente-agente-ou-ha-gente.html)

Bom, mas qual é o motivo de usar *a gente*, principalmente em linguagem coloquial?

Principalmente pela facilidade da conjugação verbal, da mesma que os falantes de PT-BR preferem o *você* ao invés do *tu*.